# Using "\n" in scanf() in C

Tags: c, scanf

I mistakenly used `scanf("%d\n",&val);` in one of my programmes, I could not understand the behavior, the function showed.

```
int main(){
    int val;
    scanf("%d\n", &val);
    printf("%d\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program required 2 integer inputs, and prints the first input that was entered.
What difference should that extra `\n` brings?

I tried to search but couldn't find the answer, even through manual of `scanf`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An `'\n'` - or any whitespace character - in the format string consumes an entire (possibly empty) sequence of whitespace characters in the input. So the `scanf` only returns when it encounters the next non-whitespace character, or the end of the input stream (e.g. when the input is redirected from a file and its end is reached, or after you closed stdin with Ctrl-D).

Answer (score 12):

From `man scanf` in my Linux box:

> A directive is one of the following:
>
> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.

BTW, `%d` is also a *directive*.

So your `"%d\n"` has two directives, the first one reads the number and the second one... well reads any amount of white space, including your end-of-lines. You have to type any non-white space character to make it stop.