# why does scanf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",&a,&b,&c); accepts 4 inputs. It has to accept 3 inputs but expects and accepts 4 inputs

Tags: c, scanf

Why does the following `scanf` statement accept 4 inputs, while it has to accept 3 inputs?

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  scanf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",&a,&b,&c);
  return 0;
}
```

It has to accept 3 inputs but expects and accepts 4 inputs. It doesn't work if I give 3 inputs. 
If I remove the 3rd \n character, then the program accepts 3 inputs.

Comment: try printing the provided inputs

Comment: Please post a fully compilable example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: why are those `\n` are there?

Answer (score 2):

The program only *appears* to accept  4 inputs into `scanf()`.

```
int a,b,c;
scanf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",&a,&b,&c);
```

With each `"%d`, `scanf()` reads
1) any leading white-space including  `' '` and `'\n'` and other white-space then
2) it reads in the digits to form the `int` until it reads a non-digit, usually the `\n`.
3) This extra `char` is put back into `stdio` for subsequent scanning.

The `\n` tells `scanf()` to read in, and not save, *any* number of white-space, not just only `'\n'`.  Reads will *continue* until a non-white-space is read.  That non-white-space is put back into `stdio` for subsequent scanning.

So with 3 sets of `"%d\n"`, once needs to enter the below for `scanf()` to read 3 `ints` and complete.

```
optional-white-space  (+-)[1 or more 0-9]  optional-white-space
optional-white-space  (+-)[1 or more 0-9]  optional-white-space
optional-white-space  (+-)[1 or more 0-9]  optional-white-space 1-non-white-space
```

Remember the non-white-space was put back for subsequent I/O.  This short program never tried reading it again.

Since `stdin` is typically buffered, that last `non-white-space` needs a following `\n` before the console gives the line to `stdin`.

---

The best way to handle user I/O is to first get the line of text with `fgets()`, then use `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, `strtof()` or `strtok()` to parse the received line.

```
// Example reading 1 `int` per line
int a[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
  char buf[40];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)== NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &a[i]) != 1) Handle_ParseError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

scanf functions the same thing which is written into "".So if you write 
scanf("\n%d\n%d\n",&a,&b); it is accepting a newline digit newline digit newline.
so for the sake of simplicity we write scanf("%d%d",&a,&b); if we have to take two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `\n` from your `scanf`

```
 scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
```

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15443523/2648826) info here.

Comment: yeah it works then..but why does it accept 4 inputs if I give \n

Comment: @user3219361 Go through the link posted. And if you consider `\n` as an input (which is actually not considered as one and is not stored in your variables) then you are infact giving 6 _inputs_ and not 3 as you would expect.

Comment: As you have mentioned \n in your scanf, it simply expect any non-white-space input.

Answer (score -2):

When we give "\n" in "scanf",it means that the number our input given till we press enter is ought to be considered as one string but here we don't have enough variables to store the inputs seperated by "space" as well as "enter" so the extra variables are discarded and the once that are stored in the variables for the first time are used as the primary values but if we dynamically allocate the memory in an array and then put something like "array[^\n]" in the scanf then in can consider the whole entered input as a single string.

Comment: The lack of punctuation really weakens your answer.