# scanf and "\n" escape sequence

Tags: c, escaping, sequence, scanf

I do not understand the functioning of scanf instruction

```
int i;
scanf("\n");
printf("hello!\n");
scanf("%d",&i);
printf(%d",i);
```

so the the second scanf don't let me type the second input, and it take only the first value why ?

Comment: what's your first and second input?

Comment: you can choose any two integers number

Comment: you might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443483/using-n-in-scanf-in-c

Comment: actually I have seen this post before I ask my question, but realy I don't understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you (for example) input `2[space][space][space]`, the whitespaces will be consumed by `\n`, even your "enter"! (when you actually want to confirm your input)..
and your `2` will be stored in variable `i`..

this `\n` will keep scanning until it finds a non-whitespace character, such as: **your second int input**.. but of course it's not stored in any variable (see your code)!

so at last, it returns and print out the value of variable `i`; which is `2`..

Comment: but why it is stored directely in i variable whitout ask me to type the second input when it execute the second scanf

Comment: because your `2` is not consumed by `\n` (it only consumes non-whitespaces), so it's still there **to be consumed** by **the one who wants it**, in this case, your **second scanner**..