# %lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'double *'

Tags: c

Why am I getting this warning while trying to compile my program?
`%lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'double *'`
I'm using CodeBlocks IDE, But these lines give a huge number:

```
double calculate1 = mealPrice * (double)(percentage)/100;
printf("The tip that you should leave is %lf \n", &calculate1);
```

I'm new to C programming and still learning stuff.

```
// CS 262, Lab Section <208>
// Lab 2

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   printf("Enter the price of the meal: \n");
   double mealPrice = 0;
   scanf("%lf\n", &mealPrice);

   printf("Now enter the tip percentage: \n");
   int percentage = 0;
   scanf("%d\n", &percentage);


   //Calculates tip amount in double, int, and float types
   double calculate1 = mealPrice * (double)(percentage)/100;
   printf("The tip that you should leave is %lf \n", &calculate1);
   int calculate2 = (int)mealPrice * (int)(percentage/100);
   printf("The tip that you should leave is %d\n", &calculate2);
   float calculate3 = (float)mealPrice * (float)(percentage/100);
   printf("The tip that you should leave is &f\n", &calculate3);

   //Add tip to meal price
   double total = calculate1 + mealPrice;
   printf("The total price including tips is %lf\n", total);

   printf("The meal cost is %f\nThe tip percentage is %d\nThe tip amount is%lf\nThe total cost is %lf\n", &mealPrice, &percentage, &calculate1, &total);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code compiles fine for me on gcc 4.8.2., and works as expected.

Comment: @ChrisBeck, but it gives a huge number when I run `double calculate1 = mealPrice * (double)(percentage)/100;`. `percentage` is a type of `int`

Comment: John, does it not compile, or does it give a huge number? Your post indicated a compiler error. Please post the complete code you are actually working with.

Comment: @ChrisBeck, code is updated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you should not use pointers with `printf` (unless you are using pointer format specifiers). You generally pass things by pointer to `scanf` (because it needs to change them) and by value to `printf` (because it's not supposed to change them). That's why you are getting huge numbers.

It should look like:

```
printf("The tip that you should leave is %lf \n", calculate1);
```

and

```
scanf("%lf\n", &mealPrice);
```

not

```
printf("The tip that you should leave is %lf \n", &calculate1);
```

or

```
scanf("%lf\n", mealPrice);
```

Also in the future, don't show us compiler warnings unless they are specifically connected to the code that you posted, or you are going to get confused responses.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @ChrisBeck, but one more thing: when it asks to `"Enter the price of the meal:\n"` I have to enter numbers twice (separated by Enter) instead of only once. Please could you please explain that?

Comment: To be honest I think you should just follow the advice in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Comment: Also here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443483/using-n-in-scanf-in-c