# After hitting enter to get the user input using scanf, just a new line created

Tags: c

after running the program it asks for age but do not take the input

```
int main()
{
float age1, age2, age3, avg;
age1 = age2 = 24.0;
printf("How old are you?\n");
scanf("%f\n",&age3);

avg = (age1+age2+age3)/3;
printf("the average age is %f\n",avg);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove `\n` in scanf statement or you can put it before format specifier like `\n%f`

Comment: Seriously age in the float? why so we don't say i m 24.25 years old? perhaps unsigned int?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "\n" in scanf() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443483/using-n-in-scanf-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `\n` from the end of your `scanf()` format.  Any run of one or more whitespace characters (e.g. spaces, tabs, newlines, ...) in the format matches a run of any number of the same.  Thus, your `scanf()` keeps matching whitespace -- as many newlines as you choose to enter, for example -- until it sees the next *non*-whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` in `scanf("%f\n",&age3);` is causing the problem. remove the `\n`. refer [Using "\n" in scanf() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443483/using-n-in-scanf-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%f",&age3);`

Try with this