# Allocating Memory to String at runtime

Tags: c, realloc

I am writing a program to count the occurrence of '2' followed by '1' in a sting.
I dynamically allocated string

Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

    int penalty_shoot(char* s){
        int count=0,i=0;
        while(s[i]!='\0'){
           if(s[i]=='2')
                if(s[i+1]=='1')
                    count++;
        i++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    int main() {
        int t;
        int i=0;
        scanf("%d",&t);           //t is for number of test cases.
        while(t--){
            char *str, c;
            str = (char*)malloc(1*sizeof(char));
            while(c = getc(stdin),c!='\n')
            {
                str[i] = c;
                i++;
                str=realloc(str,i*sizeof(char));
            }
            str[i] ='\0';
            printf("%s\n",str);
            printf("%d\n",penalty_shoot(str));

            free(str);
            str=NULL;
            i=0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Input is :

```
3
101201212110
10101
2120
```

I am facing 2 problems:

1) I feel the dynamic allocation is not working fine.I wrote the code for dynamic allocation seeing various codes on stackoverflow . (Can anyone suggest some changes.)

2) The code isn't reading '2120' as the 3rd input.
(why is it so ?)

Comment: `getc` returns an int... you must check against `EOF` too

Comment: You're also `realloc`ating one char too few...

Comment: Consider using [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html), or else [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) with [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) if your system has them. Notice the result size of `snprintf`. And don't forget to read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of *every* function that you are using.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three errors:

1. Not checking for `EOF`:

   Change `while(c = getc(stdin),c!='\n')` to `while(c=getc(stdin),c!='\n'&&c!=EOF)`
2. Reallocating with the wrong number of bytes:

   Change `str=realloc(str,i*sizeof(char));` to `str=realloc(str,(i+1)*sizeof(char));`

   After taking one character input we increment `i` (`i++`), so the next character will be stored at the `ith` position. Now, in order to store the character at `ith` position, the length of the character array must be `i+1`. So, we `realloc` with `i+1`.

   > Just for the sake of brevity, as suggested by Basile, you
   >   might as well do this:
   >
   > Change `str=realloc(str,(i+1)*sizeof(char));` to `str=realloc(str,i+1);`
   >
   > Why? Because `sizeof char` is `1` byte
3. Not consuming the `\n` after inputting `t`:

   Change `scanf("%d",&t);` to `scanf("%d ",&t);` or `scanf("%d\n",&t);`

   `scanf("%d ",&t);` or `scanf("%d\n",&t);`.

   Either of them works. Why, you ask? Read this explanation taken from another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443483/using-n-in-scanf-in-c):

   > An `\n` - or any whitespace character - in the format string consumes
   >   an entire (possibly empty) sequence of whitespace characters in the
   >   input. So the scanf only returns when it encounters the next
   >   non-whitespace character, or the end of the input stream.

Tested [here](https://ideone.com/8iHtPo).

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition,  so no need to use it

Comment: We already did i++ before  why do we need to do i+1 explicitly in realloc ?

Comment: How "%d " and "%d\n" shows same functionality here for scanf ?

Comment: @yogi I've added some explanation. Check it out.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the explanantion

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `scanf("%d ", &t);` when user input to test
then just before second while loop, which condition should be `c != '\n'`  write `c = getchar();`
and then make sure you create a char variable, i called mine clear, that receives 0 so when you loop after initiating your string you write `c = clear;` and under it `c = getchar()` again. and when you use realloc make sure you make it bigger by (i+1) since char is only the size of 1 byte.

we create the clear variable in order to clear the buffer.

it worked for me. make sure you insert the string all at once.