# Print the occurences of digit 4. - CodeChef

Tags: c

Link to the [Problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/LUCKFOUR) - LuckyFour

The code works fine on my own system, but while submitting shows wrong answer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int t, n, count;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        count=0;
        scanf("\n%d",&n);
        while(n>0)
        {
            if(n%10==4)
            {
                count++;
            }
            n=n/10;
        }
        printf("\n%d", count);
    }
}
```

Comment: `const auto str = std::to_string(t); std::cout << std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), '4') << '\n';`

Comment: `int main(void) { /* ... */ return 0; }`

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages, only use the tag corresponding to the language you're really programming in.

Comment: Suggestion: terminate lines with `'\n'`. `printf("\n%d", 42);` isn't as usual as `printf("%d\n", 42);`.

Comment: why not use getline and straightforwardly count the '4' characters? no need for conversions. YOu also assume you're reading from stdin. Is this given ? It's not explicit in the description you linked to.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma And: why not use `getc()` and print the count of '4' characters? There could be hundreds of them!

Comment: @wildplasser see my program below. The question is to output the number per line, hence this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must write outputs in end.

and also use "%d\n" instead of "\n%d"

first change these lines and check:

```
scanf("\n%d",&n);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

and

```
printf("%d\n", count); // instead of \n%d
```

if dont work save results in an array and print they in another "while"

Comment: It worked. 

By changing `int main(void)` and adding `return 0;`

Also, with this `printf("%d\n", count);`

Can you tell me what actually went wrong?

Comment: The primary problem was probably that your output didn't end with a newline.  Print lines so that they end with newlines; only add newlines at the front when you want blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using whitespace (space, newline) in scanf. Please see an earlier thread on this topic [Using “\n” in scanf() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443483/using-n-in-scanf-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how I'd avoid conversion: 
(also added some error checking and an actual return value for `main` which I like to have, as do Unix-like OS'es...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static size_t count_char_in_line(const char *l, size_t len, char c){
    size_t res=0;
    while(len>0){ 
        if (*(l++) == c) res++; 
        len--;
    }
    return res;
}

int main(void){

size_t nr_of_expected_lines=0;
ssize_t nr_read;
size_t line_length;
char *line = NULL;
int ret=0;

if (-1 != ( nr_read = getline(&line, &line_length, stdin))){
    if (1 != sscanf(line, "%zu", &nr_of_expected_lines)){
        fprintf(stderr, "not a number on the first line..\n");
        ret=1;
        goto cleanup;
    }
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "premature end of stdin..\n");
    ret=2;
    goto cleanup;
}
while (nr_of_expected_lines > 0 && (-1 != (nr_read = getline(&line, &line_length,stdin)))){
    if (nr_read > 1){
        size_t count=count_char_in_line(line, nr_read-1, '4');
        fprintf(stdout, "%zu\n", count);
        nr_of_expected_lines--;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "empty line error\n");
        ret= 3;
        break;
    }
}  

cleanup:
free(line);
return ret;
```

}