# why do i get Segmentation fault executing this code?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, strcpy, toupper

I'm trying to figure out the issue with this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *s;
    scanf("%s\n", s);

    char *t = malloc(sizeof(*s) + 1);

    strcpy(t, s);
    t[0] = toupper(t[0]);
    printf("s: %s\n", s);
    printf("t: %s\n", t);

    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to upper case the first alphabet of my input to get for example `hi!` changed into `Hi!`.

Comment: `scanf("%s\n",s);` is reading into uninitialized pointer, `sizeof(*s)` is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are using scanf on a char* without first allocating memory to it. This may lead to segmentation fault. In fact, the following code :

   ```c
   #include<stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
       char* str;
       scanf("%s", str);
       printf("%s\n", str);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   does give segmentation fault sometimes. Instead you can use a `char` array instead of a `char*` if you want to avoid `malloc` before `scanf` . You can use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to prevent writing out of bounds or you can check with `scanf` itself like this:

   ```c
   char s[100];
   if(scanf("%99s",s) != 1) { /* error */ }
   ```

   Also in your code, you have a `\n` after `%s` in the `scanf` statement, that I have removed(assuming you didn't intend this behaviour) . You can see what that does here: [Using "\n" in scanf() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443483/using-n-in-scanf-in-c)
2. Secondly, in allocating memory for `t`, you are using `sizeof(*s)` which is just `sizeof(char)` which is defined to be `1`. Instead, you should be using `strlen(s)+1` which will allocate one more byte than the length of s which should work fine. Also, checking if `t==NULL` is also recommended.
3. Before calling `toupper` the argument must be type-casted into an `unsigned char` to avoid the risks of undefined behaviour if the `char` type is signed on the platform. More on this can be found on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805970/18639286 (Though the question was a C++ question, the answer actually quotes C standard specifications)

I have edited the above changes into your code to get the following:

```c
int main (int argc,char* argv[])
{

    char s[100];
    if(scanf("%99s",s)!=1)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Invalid or missing input\n");
       // scanf should have returned 1 if it successfully read 1 input
    }
    char *t = malloc(strlen(s) + 1); // to store the letters + '\0' at the end
    if(t==NULL)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
       exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(t, s);
    t[0] = toupper((unsigned char)t[0]);
    printf("s: %s\n", s);
    printf("t: %s\n", t);

    free(t);
    return 0;

}
```

**Some extra points:**

You can also use `fgets` instead of `scanf` :
`fgets(s, 100, stdin);` as `fgets` does bound checking.

Also, fgets reads till end of line/file or till the buffer is full, so it will read past the spaces in input, But `scanf` will stop at a space. Or as Ted Lyngmo pointed out in the comments, **`scanf` with `%s` reads a word, while `fgets` reads a line**.

But, even if you intend to read only a word, you can use `fgets` and then use `sscanf` to read the first word from the string with which you used `fgets`. Example:

```
char buffer[20];
char str[sizeof buffer]=""; //initialize with an empty string
if(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)==NULL)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error reading input\n");
  exit(1);
}
if(sscanf(buffer, "%s", str)!=1)
{
  // if str was not read
  fprintf(stderr, "String not read\n");
  exit(1);
}
// DO stuff with str
```

Here, you don't need to use `%19s` because we know the size of `buffer`.

Comment: @chqrlie added the ```unsigned char``` conversion for ```toupper``` and initialized ```str``` to empty string now.

Comment: OK. `scanf()` is a pain, but getting rid of it is not simple :)

Comment: Yes, Checking the return value of ```sscanf``` instead of using ```strcmp``` after the ```sscanf``` seems better. But as I keep modifying the code for using fgets for reading a word, I feel like using ```scanf``` with the width specifier seems so much simpler.

Comment: I think they both have their uses and using them in combination like you do with `fgets` + `sscanf` is often the most secure/less error prone option.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote to the already great answer, I must recommend GNU Debugger (shortly gdb).

Run `"gdb [program name]"`, the program should be compiled with the `-g` flag. In the interactive environment, you can run that program by typing `r` which may yield some useful information. Typing `"b <number>"` to specify a break in the runtime, then type `"s [number]"` a number of lines ahead in the program.

There are plenty of ways with gdb to extract information about the running program, I'd heavily recommend reading the docs on it.